# Cannot see existing data in WPF DataGridComboBoxColumn bound to ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I'm working on a WPF application with a DataGrid which has manually defined columns.
In that DataGrid the user shall be able to input data including a lower bound (a decimal value) and a comparer sign ("<" or "<=").

The DataGrid itself is bound to an ObservableCollection named StepDataSource:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the data of the stepfunction.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<StepData> StepDataSource
    {
        get { return stepdataSource; }
        set
        {
            stepdataSource = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StepDataSource");
        }
    }
```

The class StepData - which is not part of the viewmodel - contains the following properties:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lower bound.
    /// </summary>
    public double LowerBound { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the assigned value.
    /// </summary>
    public double StepValue { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the lower comparer.
    /// </summary>
    public ArithmeticSignData LowerComparer2 { get; set; }
```

The last property LowerComparer2 is needed for the item which was selected in the ComboBox.

One of my columns in the DataGrid is a DataGridComboBoxColumn which is bound to another ObservableCollection in my viewmodel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ArithmeticSignData> LowerComparers2 { get; set; }
```

The class ArithmeticSignData contains properties for the key and value which shall be used by the ComboBox.

```
public class ArithmeticSignData
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">The key.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    public ArithmeticSignData(string key, string value)
    {
        ArithmeticSignKey = key;
        ArithmeticSignValue = value;
    }

    public string ArithmeticSignKey { get; set; }

    public string ArithmeticSignValue { get; set; }

}
```

In the viewmodel i'm filling that collection:

```
        LowerComparers2 = new ObservableCollection<ArithmeticSignData>();
        LowerComparers2.Add(new ArithmeticSignData("1", "<"));
        LowerComparers2.Add(new ArithmeticSignData("2", "<="));
```

Then i defined the column in the DataGrid like that:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="grd_stepdata"
              Grid.Row="0"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Margin="5"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              CanUserDeleteRows="True"
              SelectionUnit="FullRow"
              ItemsSource="{Binding StepDataSource, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="col_LowerComparer2"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding LowerComparer2, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ArithmeticSignValue"
                                    Header="LowComp"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

By some articles in this forum i have learned that the ItemsSource has to be set in code-behind:

```
col_LowerComparer2.ItemsSource = vm.LowerComparers2;
```

When i start the app and select an item i can see in my viewmodel-property LowerComparer2 the selected item with the correct key and value.
But unfortunately i cannot see existing data from the viewmodel in the column after i started the app.

Have i forgotten one or more attributes?

Comment: Does the StepDataSource collection contain view model objects, i.e. objects of the type that where the LowerComparer2 and the LowerComparers2 properties are defined? Or what is StepDataSource and where it is defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="col_LowerComparer2"
                                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding LowerComparer2, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                    DisplayMemberPath="ArithmeticSignValue"
                                    Header="LowComp">
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.LowerComparers2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.LowerComparers2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Also note that the object returned by the LowerComparer2 property of the `StepData` object must be present in the LowerComparers2 collection of the `MainViewModelClass` for an item to be selected. This means that you can't set this property to a *new* `ArithmeticSignData` object. You should set it to any of the `ArithmeticSignData` objects that have already been added to the LowerComparers2 collection:

```
using System.Linq;
...

public MainWindow()
{
    // The window components are initialized.
    InitializeComponent();

    // DataContext gets the viewmodel.
    DataContext = vm;

    vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 0, 0, vm.LowerComparers2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArithmeticSignKey == "1")));
    vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<=", 0.1, 0.8, vm.LowerComparers2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArithmeticSignKey == "2")));
    vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 0.2, 1.2, vm.LowerComparers2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArithmeticSignKey == "1")));
    vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<=", 0.3, 1.4, vm.LowerComparers2.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ArithmeticSignKey == "2")));
    ChartDataRefresh();

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You mm8. With the first example the ItemsSource-binding works now in XAML too. But i can't still see the existing data in column col_LowerComparer2. Meanwhile i uploaded the files of my solution into a GitHub-repository: https://github.com/patrickpirzer/StepFunctions

Comment: Hello mm8. The ItemsSource-binding works now in XAML too, but i still can't the the existing data in the column "col_LowerComparer2" after i started the app. Meanwhile i imported the files of my app into a GitHub-repository: https://github.com/patrickpirzer/StepFunctions

Comment: The binding does work but you still can't see the data? What does that mean?

Comment: It means that i have prepared some data for the DataGrid in the constructor of the MainWindow (as You can see now in my GitHub-repository). In the DataGrid i have two columns: col_LowerComparer and col_LowerComparer2. After the app has started i see data in the first column but not in the second. Further i have found a small mistake in the first version of Your solution. The SelectedItemBinding must bind to LowerComparer2 directly because this property is part of the class StepData which is the type of the ObservableCollection StepDataSource to which the DataGrid is bound.

Comment: If LowerComparer2 is part of the StepData class you should use the second markup snippet. Do LowerComparers2 and LowerComparer2 belong to the same class?

Comment: No they don't belong to the same class. LowerComparers2 (the list with the ComboBoxItems) is part of MainWindowViewModel. And LowerComparer2 is a property of StepData which is the type of the ObservableCollection StepDataSource (another property of the MainWindowViewModel). You can see that in detail at  github.com/patrickpirzer/StepFunctions.

Comment: What about FirstOrDefault? I added the library System.Linq to ArithmeticSignData but this doesn't help.

Comment: FirstOrDefault() is a LINQ method. Did you add the using directive (using System.Linq) at the top of the code-behind file where the other using directives are?

Comment: You could also simply access the object by index: vm.StepDataSource.Add(new StepData("<", 0, 0, vm.LowerComparers2[0]));

Comment: Hello mm8. Thanks a lot for Your precious time and help. Your edited solution is THE SOLUTION. Concerning LINQ i had to add to import System.Linq in MainWindowViewModel.Now the DataGridComboBoxColumn works as expected. I will upload the final version to GitHub. There are many articles concerning that problem, but not all are constructive. All roads lead to Rome. ;)